# Problems with counters and frame splitting commands and environments in beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, counters

Using the package `gb4e` for linguists in the `beamer` environment in combination with frame splitting commands `\pause` or environments `overprint`, I face the following problem: The number are "jumping" strangely.

The same happens when I use the `beispiel` environment (see below) in combination with `\pause` command or the splitting environments. Therefore, I believe, that it is a general problem of a certain kind of counters with these commands and environments. My question is: How do I avoid this odd jumping behaviour? (In regard to the `gb4e` based environment the answer is more important. The other I just provided to show the general nature of this problem. However, I would like to see a possible solution here as well, to get a deeper understanding of LaTeX.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{Bergen}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %dt. Silbentrennung
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}

  \usepackage{gb4e}

  \newcounter{beispz} %Beispiele mit durchgehender Nummerierung und  in italics
\newenvironment{beispiel}
    {\stepcounter{beispz}
    \begin{enumerate}\item[(\arabic{beispz})]\linespread{1}\em}
    {\end{enumerate}} %\label{\stepcounter{beispz}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{exe}
\ex Du bist mir ein feiner Freund!\pause
\ex A: Wie viele Einwohner hat New York?
\end{exe}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{beispiel} asdfas\end{beispiel} \pause

\begin{beispiel} hand\end{beispiel}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Remark: Werner gave a possible solution. It involves manually setting the counter number by adding `\addtocounter{}{+previous no}` in front of the counting environment and using `\addtocounter{}{-last no}` in the end of the environment (see below). For example:

`\begin{beispiel}a\end{beispiel}\pause \begin{beispiel}b\end{beispiel}\addtocounter{beispz}{-2}\pause.`

It works. But

As you can imagine, it involves a great deal of manual work if you are preparing a larger document. Therefore, I would like to ask if there is anyone out there who knows a solution that needs considerably less effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution in a post [Re: Ling-TeX: Beamer, gb4e example numbering and the \pause command](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.linguistics/830) by Alan Munn. By adding `\resetcounteronoverlays{exx}`to the preamble, it can be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

[`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) does a lot of legwork in the background when you use the `\pause` command. In fact, to maintain the correct vertical/horizontal alignment, it still has to process whatever is presented *after* `\pause`, even though it is not printed on that particular slide. As such, it also parses the contents, incrementing counters as it going along. The following exaggerates this problem, but acts as a prime example:

[image: Counter problems in beamer with \pause]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\newcounter{beispz} %Beispiele mit durchgehender Nummerierung und  in italics
\newenvironment{beispiel}
  {\stepcounter{beispz}
   \begin{enumerate}\item[(\arabic{beispz})]\linespread{1}\em}
  {\end{enumerate}} %\label{\stepcounter{beispz}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{beispiel} abc\end{beispiel} \pause
\begin{beispiel} def\end{beispiel}
\begin{beispiel} ghi\end{beispiel}
\begin{beispiel} jkl\end{beispiel}
\end{frame}
```

\end{document}​

Slide 1 only sets `(1) abc` with the correct counter. However, it also processes the remaining `beispiel` environment on slide 1, leaving the `beispz` counter at `4` at the end of slide 1. Then it reprocesses the `frame` to produce the second slide, this time starting with `(5) abc`, as expected.

To avoid this, you have to know which counters are being manipulated and compensate for them via `\addtocounter{<cntr>}{<num>}`. Here is you example, modified to match with the correct layout:

[image: Correct counters displayed with \pause]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{gb4e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/gb4e

\newcounter{beispz} %Beispiele mit durchgehender Nummerierung und  in italics
\newenvironment{beispiel}
  {\stepcounter{beispz}
   \begin{enumerate}\item[(\arabic{beispz})]\linespread{1}\em}
  {\end{enumerate}} %\label{\stepcounter{beispz}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{exe}
  \ex Du bist mir ein feiner Freund!\pause
  \ex A: Wie viele Einwohner hat New York? \addtocounter{xnumi}{-2}
\end{exe}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{beispiel} abc\end{beispiel} \pause
\begin{beispiel} def\end{beispiel} 
\begin{beispiel} ghi\end{beispiel}
\begin{beispiel} jkl\end{beispiel} \addtocounter{beispz}{-4}
\end{frame}
\end{document}​
```

The counter associated with the first environment `exe` is `xnumi` (from looking at the source code of [`gb4e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gb4e)), while that of the second `beispiel` is, of course, `beispz`.

Comment: Hi Werner, It took me some time to apply your solution to more complex presentations. The result works but is not very handy. You have to adjust every new beispiel and/or exe environments manually by first adding the \addtocounter{}{+previous no} and in the end of the environment using \addtocounter{}{-last no}. For example: \begin{beispiel}a\end{beispiel}\pause
\begin{beispiel}b\end{beispiel}\addtocounter{beispz}{-2}\pause
\addtocounter{beispz}{+2}
\begin{beispiel}c\end{beispiel}\addtocounter{beispz}{-3}\pause.
Adjustments in longer documents might be very unpleasant.

Comment: @Philip: This is fundamental to `beamer`. Not only that, in general, you could be in any environment and requesting a counter adjustment - something that `beamer` would not be able to "just pick up". So, manual intervention seems the only alternative.

Comment: For me - as not trained in computer science - it seems strange that it has to be done by manual adjustments. Because other counting environments like `enumerate` aren´t affected by commands like `\pause`. Initially, I thought/imagined that this environments come with a different kind of counter or that this environments are processed by latex on a more fundamental level, maybe before `beamer` splits the frames in different slides. So I was hoping for a adjustments in these areas.